# undefined method `friends' for #<Spree::User:0x00007fbb6ec88f80>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

Trying to build a friends feature on top of a Solidus framework, but the .friends method does not work. It does in rails console, however.

SpreeUsers Controller (current_spree_user.friends causes error):

```
class SpreeUsersController < ApplicationController
  def my_friends
    @friendships = current_spree_user.friends
  end

  def search
    @spree_users = SpreeUser.search(params[:search_param])
    render json: @spree_users
  end
end
```

Friendship Model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spree_user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'SpreeUser'
end
```

SpreeUser Model:

```
class SpreeUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

Error:
undefined method `friends' for # Did you mean? friendly_id?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4F8K.png

Console Input/Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuVjb.png

Comment: Have you restarted your development server?

Comment: yes, same error occurs

Comment: Can you show the console commands (input and output) you use when it does work please?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my post to include a picture of the console.

Comment: Thanks, as an aside, that console output might include your email. I would think about maybe cropping it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have blurred it out

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what is happening here.

You have declared a model `SpreeUser` with a `friends` relationship. This is why in your console it works. You are correctly calling the friends method on the class `SpreeUser`.

The error you are receiving is for the class `Spree::User` (Note the different class names). I am assuming you are using `spree_auth_devise` which provides that class.

You will need to properly add your logic from `SpreeUser` to `Spree::User`. I believe Spree/Solidus recommends doing so using decorators.

EG

```
Spree::User.class_eval do

    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, through: :friendships

end
```

Above not tested and a best guess taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955406/howto-extend-the-spreeuser-class-from-the-rails-app-that-uses-the-solidus-gem)

You could also test my theory by running `Spree::User.first.friends` in your console. You should receive a similar error to the browser.

Comment: Sorry, a bit new to Solidus/Ruby on Rails. Where should I add in the code you suggested?

Comment: That answer can be found in the spree docs: https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/customization/logic.html. but this would go in `app/models/spree/user_decorator.rb`

Comment: So I made the new folder spree in models and created the the user_decorator.rb file with the code you specified, but the same error occurs.